# How save input fields value created dynamically in Wordpress save_post hook action?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm developing a plugin that create a custom post type.
I've created a custom meta box with a custom meta input field.
With an AJAX function, I duplicate the input field. They are the same name and the same class.
It's all ok, but how can I save these data with `save_post` hook action?

If I use the classic function, with `update_post_meta`, it's save only last value.
I need to create an array and pass it to the save function.
How?

If I use admin-ajax.php how can I pass the `post_id` for `update_post_meta` in callback function?
I don't wanna use wpalchemy.

Comment: The last part `admin-ajax` seems to be [*another question*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)...

Answer (score 0):

The input filed **`name`** has to be in array format: `field_name[]`.

In the `<form>`:

```
<td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="name[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="url[]" value="http://" /></td>
```

Then in `save_post` action:

```
$names = $_POST['name'];
$urls = $_POST['url'];
$count = count( $names );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) 
{
    if ( $names[$i] != '' ) 
    {
        $new[$i]['name'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $names[$i] ) ); // Sanitization

        if ( $urls[$i] == 'http://' )
            $new[$i]['url'] = '';
        else
            $new[$i]['url'] = stripslashes( $urls[$i] );
    }
}

if ( !empty( $new ) && $new != $old )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'repeatable_fields', $new );
```

<sub>*Example adapted [from here](https://gist.github.com/da1nonly/2057532).*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ! It's perfect !
I use

```
$new[$i]['name'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( htmlentities($names[$i]) ) );
```

for special chars like 'à,è,ì,ò,ù' and it works perectly !

Thanks !